# Why is the IF function not working?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a problem in excel, I want to make mathematical equation, I've tried it and I have problem with that function, it gives me error. I want have result in `G6` 
if i type `W` in `F6`, then it will type in `G6 : E6`
if i type `L` in `F6`, then it will type in `G6 : -D6`
i think that I can get `-D6` by multiplying `D6` with `-1`

[image: Link]

Note: KDYŽ means `IF` in my language

Comment: Please revise your question. See if you can improve the clarity a bit. It's very hard to make sense of what you're trying to do. See here: [How do I ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can get by multiplying D6 by -1 provided D6 is formatted to be a number.  **It currently isn't**.

Comment: its easy to undestand, i need result in G6 and .... IF i type W in F6 , then itll just copy what is in E6 ... and IF i type L in F6, then ill copy what is in D6 and multiply it with -1

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: CharlieRB, as you can see in the picture, it dont type anything, it just copy function into the cell.

Comment: You said "*I've tried it and I have problem with that function, it gives me error*", so what it the error? Is it a `Name?` or `#N/A` error?

Comment: may i said it little bit wrong, i apologize for my english, the error means  copying function in the cell

Comment: So what does it display in the cell.  If its an empty cell that means your syntax is wrong.  As I pointed out you can't multiple a cell by -1 if it isn't formatted to be a number.

Comment: I try explain it again, i want to put result in G6, the result is : if I put W into F6, then it will write E6 ---- if I put L into F6, then it will write D6 * -1.  --- that is the result - i want just to assign another functions on W and another on L

Comment: You can't multiply the text value of `270C`. It will cause an error. Are you trying to achieve the results of `269C` if `F6` is "L"?

Comment: no, i am trying to achieve -270 in this case, and in case of "W" i am trying to achieve +130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this answer will help you resolve the problem you are having. It appears there are a couple issues with your formula.

1. You need to use quotation marks around the `L` and `W` in the `IF`
   logical test.

   `=IF(F6="L", D6*-1, IF(F6="W", E6,))`
2. You can not perform a mathematical operation on a text value of `270C`. To accomplish
   this you will need to tell Excel to only use the left most values of
   cell `D6` by using the `LEFT` function. The `& "C"` replaces the text. If you don't want the `C` suffix, leave it off.

   `=IF(F6="L",SUM(LEFT(D6,3)*-1) & "C",IF(F6="W",E6,))`

Results:

[image]

Comment: i found it, i have it in my language ( czech ) and the problem is that in czech i have to replace , with ;    thank you very much